# Debian preseed.cfg - Language not set

Tags: debian, installation, automation, preseed

I'm trying to write a preseed.cfg which should be used for a full automated installation of Debian wheezy. For some reasons the installer is still asking to select a lanugage even if I set this in my preseed.cfg.

I got these options from the official Debian page:
https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/example-preseed.txt

```
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string DE
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8
# Optionally specify additional locales to be generated.
d-i localechooser/supported-locales multiselect de_DE.UTF-8
```

Comment: See my updated comment.

Answer (score 2):

Setting localization values will only work if you are using initrd preseeding. With all other methods the preseed file will only be loaded after these questions have been asked.

To get this working there are two options:

1. Setting localization as kernel parameters
2. Building a custom netinstall iso with a preseeding.cfg

Comment: I think in 2. it should be `preseed.cfg` instead of `preseeding.cfg` (https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso)

Comment: Can you give example where to set the localization as kernel parameters?

Answer (score 1):

If you use **build-simple-cdd** then the parameters to skip language and keyboard questions are:

`build-simple-cdd --keyboard us --locale en_US.UTF-8`

The reason for that is that the pressed is loaded after setting these, just like @denny-crane said.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your preseed settings are correct.

Did you set ***priority=critical*** in the boot parameter? That will prevent the installer from asking any questions, except critical ones.

Also did you try to set ***console-setup/layoutcode=us*** in the boot parameter? I remember that would get rid of the last question about the keymap, it may help in your case.

Comment: I tried several options like "high" and and "critical" but this did not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does your installer ask for the *keyboard* language?

We use the following language-related definitions in our preseed file, and the (standard PXEbooted) installer doesn't ask us anything about language.

```
# Locale, country and keyboard settings
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i console-setup/modelcode string pc105
d-i console-setup/variant USA
d-i console-setup/layout USA
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us
# for Debian 7 and later
d-i keymap select us
```

Answer (score 0):

When booting on the Ubuntu Installation device (CD or USB disk), the `syslinux` bootloader asks first for a language, before displaying the boot menu (that would eventually run a preseed file).

In order to select automatically a language, you should

1. **Set the chosen language in the `syslinux/langlist` file** by removing the other languages.
2. **Set a non-null timeout in the `syslinux/syslinux.cfg` file**, expressed in deci-seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out this one. The answer is the order is important. Put locale first then language. Change this

```
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string DE
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8
```

into this

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string DE
```

Comment: That didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

## This worked for me !

To set English as language and Germany as country, and use a German keyboard layout:
/install.amd/vmlinuz vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/gtk/initrd.gz language=en country=DE locale=en_US.UTF-8 keymap=de --- quiet

I did this in my grub.cfg (in boot/grub)

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu Server 14.04 I was able to get past the language selection list by creating a file named "lang" with one line "en" (for selecting English) in isolinux directory.