# virt-install preseed not working

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ansible, virsh

I have setup a pre-seed for the vm install but it still asks me for location first.

My vm install is being trigger by a bash script `create_vm.sh`:

```
virt-install --name test \
    --boot uefi \
    --machine q35 \
    --ram 16384 \
    --disk path=/mnt/vms/images.img,format-qcow2 \
    --vcpus 4 \
    --os-type linux \
    --network bridge:br0,model=virtio \
    --graphics none \
    --console pty,target_type=serial \
    --location='http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-amd64/' \
    --extra-args='ks=file:/preseed_test.cfg console=tty50,115200n8 serial' \
    --initrd-inject=/tmp/preseed_test.cfg \
    --virt-type kvm
```

in my preseed, I have:

```
### localisation
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string AU
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_GB.UTF-8
```

but these questions still pop up?
why is that?

the rest of the preseed seems to work though.

Comment: Do you have the same problems with any value? Did you try with just language+country, without the locale?

Comment: Also see: https://serverfault.com/a/864587/396475  it seems you need to specify the keyboard to make sure to skip all questions on language

Comment: it is just the `[11] Select your location` part it seems the other bits can preseed fine. But if I run the script myself in the shell without using ansible it seems to work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just now.. I believe that `locale` sets the country and language - and it looks like you're setting the country using the `country` field differently to the country used in the `locale` field

I didn't test setting all 3 options at once, I just moved to setting only the `locale` to `en_AU.UTF-8`